# Mocking an instance object created via Constructor

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have this snippet:

```py
#jira_api.py
from jira import JIRA

class JiraApi:
    def __init__(self):
        username = os.environ.get("JIRA_USERNAME")
        api_token = os.environ.get("JIRA_TOKEN")

        options = {'server': 'https://mycompany.atlassian.net'}

        try:
            self.jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=(username, api_token))
        except jira.exceptions.JIRAError:
            print("[ERROR] Unable to connect to JIRA with provided credentials.")
            sys.exit(1)

    def search(self, query):
      return self.jira.search_issues(query)
```

Is there a way I could patch this constructor so that the value of `self.jira` is my own mocked object? I would like to replace

```py
self.jira = JIRA(options=options, basic_auth=(username, api_token))
```

with my own object, if possible, so that the constructor doesn't actually try to connect to the API. I tried a few approaches already, specifically to patch `JIRA` to return my own mocked object... with no luck though.

**Example attempt**:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def patched_jira_api(mocker):
    def _patched_jira_api(jira_issues):
        mocked_jira_client = mocker.MagicMock()
        mocked_jira_client.search_issues = mocker.MagicMock(return_value=jira_issues)

        return mocker.patch('jira_api.JIRA', return_value=mocked_jira_client)

    return _patched_jira_api

def test_jira_basics(patched_jira_api, mock_jira_issue):
    mock_issues = [
        mock_jira_issue(priority="P0"),
        mock_jira_issue(priority="P1")
    ]
    patched_jira_client(mock_issues)
    jira_api = JiraApi()

    assert jira_api.search(query='TEST') == mock_issues
```

My goal is to mock `self.jira.search_issues` built-in function to return my `mock_issues` list, but my constructor is still trying to connect to the real JIRA server. :(

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE**: I tried to update the module name from `jira.py` to `jira_api.py` to avoid any namespace issues. However, now I get a failure when trying to patch:

```
    def _importer(target):
        components = target.split('.')
        import_path = components.pop(0)
>       thing = __import__(import_path)
E       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jira_api'
```

Comment: Is your module with `JiraApi` really `jira.py`? Because you also do `from jira import JIRA` in that same module. You are probably patching the wrong `JIRA` reference.

Comment: I agree, seems there is a namespace collision happening here

Comment: I renamed the file & test file to `jira_api.py` but still the real JIRA constructor is not being patched, and it's connecting to the real instance.

Comment: You have to change the `patch` location to `jira_api.JIRA` in this case, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen When I made that change, I got an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jira_api'`. Updated OP to reflect the change

Comment: I don't know your module layout, but that means that the module is not in the path. Maybe you have another top-level directory you have to add? Basically, the path should be importable from the test. In your case `import jira_api` probably does not work in the test. It also depends on the path you call `pytest` (or rather `python -m pytest`) from.

Comment: The tests run from the root folder. So I updated the `mocker.patch` call to be: `return mocker.patch('qualitymetrics.api.jira_api.JIRA', return_value=mocked_client)`... but now, my test is just literally _hanging_... no response whatsoever. I have to `kill -9` my process to stop it (Ctrl C doesn't work)